# R: image intensities in the log scale

Tags: r, image, plot

I have a matrix of probabilities:

```
x <- matrix(runif(16384), ncol = 128)
image(x)
```

Now, I would like to have the x (image intensities that are representing the "probabilities") imaged in a log scale.

Any easy suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`image` allows flexibility in setting the breakpoints for coloring using the `breaks` argument.  You can set the color breaks to happen according to a logarithmic scale:

```
library(viridis) # you don't need this package, I'm just using it for color palette

colorBreaks = 10^(seq(-6, 0, by = 1)) # set color breaks however you want

image(x, breaks = colorBreaks, col = rev(magma(length(colorBreaks) - 1L)))
# use whatever color palette you want.  I used magma() from viridis
```

There must be one more break than there are colors, which is why I put `-1L` in `col = rev(inferno(length(colorBreaks) - 1L))`
[image]